# How to make an EditText to only Accept an IP Address as input?

Tags: android

Here is my EditText and want to make it to accept only a IP address. I used numberDecimal as inputType but its not accepting more than one point.

```
<EditText
                android:id="@+id/etBannedIpAddress"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:hint="IP Address"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
                android:textColor="@color/blue_text" />
```

Comment: wait I am just trying it. :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

try like this:
by using input filter we can filter the data before entering the value only.

```
InputFilter[] filters = new InputFilter[1];
        filters[0] = new InputFilter() {
            @Override
            public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
                    android.text.Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
                if (end > start) {
                    String destTxt = dest.toString();
                    String resultingTxt = destTxt.substring(0, dstart)
                            + source.subSequence(start, end)
                            + destTxt.substring(dend);
                    if (!resultingTxt
                            .matches("^\\d{1,3}(\\.(\\d{1,3}(\\.(\\d{1,3}(\\.(\\d{1,3})?)?)?)?)?)?")) {
                        return "";
                    } else {
                        String[] splits = resultingTxt.split("\\.");
                        for (int i = 0; i < splits.length; i++) {
                            if (Integer.valueOf(splits[i]) > 255) {
                                return "";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }

        };
        editTxxt.setFilters(filters);
```

Comment: The only disadvantage is that to enter IP it shows the full-keyboard (not the numeric pad) when entering the IP value

Answer (score 12):

**Approach 1**: Using input filter, Try below code:

```
EditText text = new EditText(this);
    InputFilter[] filters = new InputFilter[1];
    filters[0] = new InputFilter() {
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
            if (end > start) {
                String destTxt = dest.toString();
                String resultingTxt = destTxt.substring(0, dstart) + source.subSequence(start, end) + destTxt.substring(dend);
                if (!resultingTxt.matches ("^\\d{1,3}(\\.(\\d{1,3}(\\.(\\d{1,3}(\\.(\\d{1,3})?)?)?)?)?)?")) { 
                    return "";
                } else {
                    String[] splits = resultingTxt.split("\\.");
                    for (int i=0; i<splits.length; i++) {
                        if (Integer.valueOf(splits[i]) > 255) {
                            return "";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        return null;
        }
    };
    text.setFilters(filters);
```

It checks for the presence of four digits, separated by dots and none of them bigger than 255. The validation occurs in real time, i.e., while typing.

But you need to write a custom input filter code like above.

**Approach 2:** Add `android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"` and `android:digits="0123456789."`

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/ip_address"
    android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
    android:digits="0123456789."
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: if you followed second approach it will accept invalid ip address also.

Comment: I am sure there must be a separate validation check for the ip address range (means correct and incorrect ) in asker's code. It is just a validation of input without implementing input filter

Comment: i have used your code its working fine but on that edittext keyboard is showing alphabetical by default.

Comment: this is the best one, the xml approach, it's the users problem exceeding 255 or negative numbers, the same error msg must be shown if no ip found or the ip is stupid

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do that in Kotlin and also add a PORT to the IP.

```
private fun setEditText() {
    val input = binding.etPuerto
    input.inputType = InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD
    val filters = arrayOfNulls<InputFilter>(1)
    filters[0] = filterIP()
    input.filters = filters
}

private fun filterIP(): InputFilter {
    return InputFilter { source, start, end, dest, dstart, dend ->
        if (attr.end > start) {
            val destTxt = dest.toString()
            val resultingTxt = (destTxt.substring(0, dstart)
                    + source.subSequence(start, end)
                    ) + destTxt.substring(dend)
            if (!resultingTxt.matches(
                    Regex(
                        "^\\d{1,3}(\\.(\\d{1,3}(\\.(\\d{1,3}(\\.(\\d{1,3}(:(\\d{1,5})?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?"
                    )
                )
            )
                return@InputFilter ""
        }
        null
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

private static final String IPV4_REGEX =
            "^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\." +
                    "(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\." +
                    "(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\." +
                    "(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$";

    private static final Pattern IPv4_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(IPV4_REGEX);
```

after

```
boolean verifyIP()
    {
        String ip = textview.getText().toString();
        if (ip == null) return false;

        Matcher matcher = IPv4_PATTERN.matcher(ip);
        return matcher.matches();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Split the input string to determine whether it is greater than 255. Unfortunately, the format cannot be verified in this way.

```java
class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String test = "192.192.10.1";
        String[] arr = test.split("\\.");
        if (arr.length != 4){
            return;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i <  arr.length; i++) {
            int x = Integer.parseInt(arr[i]);
            if (x>=255){
                System.out.println("error");
            }else{
                System.out.println(x+"");
            }
        }
    }
}
```